# C - Forks & Pipes, How do you open a process for every file to run a word count and have the parent process sum the results?

Tags: c, linux, fork

[Assignment]
So I wrote a program in C to count the number of lines, words, & characters of a file which is input (with -l -w -c modifiers included). Now I have to create as many processes as there are files on the command line with each process counting only one file and write their result to a pipe. The parent process needs to read from the pipe and display the totals. I should also display the process id which counted each file. Here is my whole program but my issue occurs in main():

```
...
    if (pipe(pd) < 0)
        error_exit("Pipe failed");
    for (i = 1; i < argc || noFile == true; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == (pid_t)0)
        {
            //I suppose this is the child process

            ...

            result = WordCount(fileRead);

            //close it up
            close(pd[1]);
            if (write(pd[1], &result, sizeof(struct CountObj)) == -1)
                error_exit("Write failed");
            return 0;
        }
        else if (pid < (pid_t)0)
        {
            //I suppose the fork failed
            error_exit("Fork failed");
        }
        else
        {
            //I suppose this is the parent process
            close(pd[0]);
            isParent = true;
            if (read(pd[0], &result, sizeof(struct CountObj)) == -1)
                error_exit("Read failed");

            ... [print counts]

            if (fileCount > 1)
            {
                total.lines += result.lines;
                total.words += result.words;
                total.chars += result.chars;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isParent == true && fileCount > 1)
    {
         ... [print totals]
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my current output:

```
ryan@chrx:~/Documents/OS-Projects/Project6_Pipes$ ./a.out multi_line short_line

ERROR: Read failed - bye!
ryan@chrx:~/Documents/OS-Projects/Project6_Pipes$
ERROR: Write failed - bye!
^C
```

I'm assuming the problem might be when reading/writing for the size of my CountObj struct. Is there anything else I might be doing wrong?

Comment: `close(pd[0]); read(pd[0]..` See any problem there?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please reduce your program to the minimal code necessary to reproduce the error. There is dozens of lines of code not related to the problem in your question; that obfuscates the actual problem.

Comment: @kaylum Okay. I feel dumb now. I'm sorry I missed that. Haha

Comment: This question is answered, but maybe you could benefit from some basic advice:: use `errno(3)`, `strerror(3)`, and/or `perror(3)` to produce useful error messages. Try using `getopts(3)` to parse arguments. There's not really any reason to have those structs, I would remove them. Define a usage function and add it to the default case on option parsing. Declare your functions in a separate header file. What's up with the ghetto booleans... don't do that. I wouldn't even compare return codes to an explicit value unless you're specifically testing for non 0/1. Use `if (test)` and `if (!test)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're catching an error because you are to read from the file that you've just closed.

```
        close(pd[0]);
        isParent = true;
        if (read(pd[0], &result, sizeof(struct CountObj)) == -1)
            error_exit("Read failed");
```

It's simple: you create a pipe before fork(), you fork():

```
//create a process for each file & print the count of words, lines & characters

if (pipe(pd) < 0)
    error_exit("Pipe failed");
for (i = 1; i < argc || noFile == true; i++)
{
    pid = fork();
```

and close one end(let's say dedicated to reading) if the code runs on child - because child needs just to write. You close(the writer fd) on the parent respectively.

Comment: Thank you. Just caught that. I apologize for my bad code.